# How to manupilate parameters/arguments parsed through Raised Events?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, events

I have this text loader class that I'm trying to write tests for. And one of it's methods does a RaiseEvent with a CancelEventArgs parsed in as an argument, so something like this:

```
Private Sub FireThisEvent()
    cancelEvent created here
    RaiseEvent HelloWorld(cancelEvent)

    If cancelEvent.Cancel Then
        'do smthg
    End If
End Sub
```

The handler for `HelloWorld` event is my UI class that makes a pop-up for the user to 
decide Yes or No, which then sets `cancelEvent.Cancel` to either `True` or `False`. And then the above method checks on `cancelEvent` and does an action accordingly.

My question is, since I'm only testing the loader class (and not the UI), how do I manipulate the `cancelEvent` after the event is raised so that I can test for when `cancelEvent.Cancel` is `True` and then , when it is `False`. Thank you.

Would I have mock the UI class?

Comment: Which testing framework?  NUnit?  MSTest?  Which mocking framework?

Comment: @StevenDoggart its NUnit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution to this was to add an event handler in the test method, so that when the event is raised, the test method will create a CancelEventAgrs and set its Cancel to True/False.

```
Public Sub TestingMethod()
        Dim txt As TextLoader = Nothing
        AddHandler TextLoader.LoadingDoneEvent,
            (Sub(e As ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)
                 e.Cancel = True
             End Sub)

        txt = New TextLoader()
        txt.FireThisEvent()
End Sub
```